# Await reaction by a different user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a verification system that if you send a message. In a different channel, an embed shows up with 2 emoji's: 1 to accept, and 1 to deny. The .awaitReaction has to be triggered by a different user then the author. But when I change the filter. It triggers the message if the bot reacts to it. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
    let register = args.join(" ").slice(7)

const filter = (reaction, user) => ["✅", "❌"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !bot.user;

let test = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.addField("User:", message.author.username && message.author.tag, true)
.addField("Requested nickname:", register)
.setColor("#ed0c75")
.setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL)

let acceptordeny = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "accept-or-deny");
if(!acceptordeny) return message.channel.send("Can't find accept or deny channel.");

acceptordeny.send(test).then(async message => {

    await message.react("✅")
    await message.react("❌")

    message.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ["time"]
    }).then(collected => {

        const reaction = collected.first();

        switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
            case "✅":
                console.log("Accepted")
                break;
            case '❌':
                console.log("Denied")
                break;
        }
    }).catch(collected => {
        return acceptordeny.send("Failed")
    })
})
```

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the filter with this one:

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => ["✅", "❌"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id !== message.client.user.id;
```

It will check if the id of the user who reacted to the message is the same as the id and if, cancel.